# hfill using any characters

Tags: macros, plain-tex, custom

Not that I badly need this but I thought it could be useful to have:

What would be an efficient code for a command like `\hfillwith` such that, say, `\hfillwith{bla}` would output `blablablablabla`... from the place the command occurs till the end of the line? Or maybe there actually is a builtin one?

Comment: Basically `\leaders\hbox{bla}\hfill`

Comment: The TeX primitives `\leaders`, `\xleaders`, and `\cleaders` provide this ability, with some differences how the leader box content is aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX offers leaders for such a job. There are three kinds of leaders:

```
\leaders
\cleaders
\xleaders
```

differing in how they treat the “missing space”. You specify either a box or a rule and a glue specification, for instance `\hfill` or some `\hskip`.

Let's make an example in plain TeX that's simpler; it works the same in LaTeX, that has no “official” interface to leaders.

```
\parindent=0pt

\hsize=0.6\hsize

\hrule
\medskip

1. some text some text some text some longer text \leaders\hbox{abc}\hfill\null

2. some text some text some text some text \leaders\hbox{abc}\hfill\null

3. some text some text some text some text \cleaders\hbox{abc}\hfill\null

4. some text some text some text some text \xleaders\hbox{abc}\hfill\null

\bye
```

When `\.leaders` (`.` stands for nothing, `c` or `x`) is followed by a box, this box is replicated as many times as it can fit the space to cover.

[image]

The rule shows the allotted text width. You can see that in lines 1 and 2, the boxes are horizontally aligned: TeX imagines an “infinite string” and cuts it where the boxes can fit entirely. In line 3 the missing space is added to either side, whereas in line 4 the space is distributed between the replicated boxes. The `\null` at the end ensures that the leaders are not discarded at a line break.

Leaders can also be used in vertical mode, but I'll skip the case.